# Tree view is expanding for public website only when connected through VPN

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, vpn

I am working in a public website and this website is developed in the Asp.Net. I am facing a strange problem in this website i.e. If I run through code in my system and local database than treeview expansion functionality which takes data from database is working fine but at the same time if I try to expand this tree view in publicly deployed website than it doesn't work.

But the strange thing is that when I connect to their Virtual private network through Citrix access gateway and than use this public website than expand functionality works fine.

Stored procedure called when this tree view expand is normal stored procedure which only takes input from the databse table through stored procedure.

Need help to figure out what can be the possible reasons.